# Python Lists -Syntax for '['

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to declare certain values in List.
Values looks like this:

```
["compute","controller"], ["compute"] ,["controller"]
```

I know the List syntax in python is

```
example = []
```

I am not sure how I will include square brackets and double quotes in the List.
Could anyone please help.

I tried the following:

```
 cls.node = ["\["compute"\]","\["controller"\]"]
 cls.node = ["[\"compute\"]","[\"controller\"]"]
```

Both did not work.

Comment: You do know that Python allows strings to be both in single and double quotes? Like you can have `'"Hello"'` for the string `"Hello"`, or `"'Hello'"` for the string `'Hello'`.

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Where is your dictionary? What do you want to have as keys?

Comment: People, please don't edit the title until OP clarifies the question.

Comment: example = [["compute","controller"], ["compute"] ,["controller"]] is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: Or maybe `["[compute]", "[controller]"]`?

Comment: example = [ str(i) for i in example]
Try this then, it will give you quotes.
["['compute', 'controller']", "['compute']", "['controller']"]

Comment: Sorry Friends, I meant List. and in hurry I typed Dictionary. I was going through so many tutorials to fix this and hence messed up while typing. Pardon my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `list` not `dictionary` because that is the syntax of a **list**:

You can simply do it using the following format `'"Hello"'`:

```
cls.node = ['["compute"]','["controller"]']
cls.node = ['["compute"]','["controller"]']
```

Demo:

```
s = ['["hello"]', '["world"]']

for i in s:
    print i

[OUTPUT]
["hello"]
["world"]
```

Comment: @juanchopanza, The OP has clearly made _some_ attempt at the problem however ineffective. Furthermore, although the OP might not know what it is called, we can fairly easily tell that the OP __did__ mean lists by the syntax of his example.